# Read a line of input including space-delimited strings and display them as a single complete line using getline

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to make a simple program(hello.cpp) that takes user input in the form of a test file using `getline` and prints it back out on the screen.

The code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    string name;
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Hello " << name << "!" << endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

The test file(test.txt) I'm using looks like this:

```
|
|
|John
|Doe
|
```

Ignore the vertical lines, I just put them there to represent the line breaks

I'm trying to get `getline` to ignore tabs and line breaks and just read what is in the text file as just one string.

The output I want looks like this:

```
$./hello < test.txt
What is your name?
Hello John Doe!
```

What I'm getting looks like this:

```
$./hello < test.txt
What is your name?
Hello !
```

Comment: Why do you want to use getline? Would be simpler if you didn't. Reading a whole file one character at a time is easy.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment that specifically asks me to use getline, there's a lot of other simpler ways to do it but I have to do it this way

Comment: Why don't you use an ifstream?

Comment: I'm don't really know how to do that

Comment: @Sean Then you probably have to use a loop to add each part of the name to a string, as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't agree with the approach you are taking here, here is how I would solve your current problem:

Since the name in `test.txt` is split across multiple lines, you have to keep using `getline` until there is no more input. Thus, you should use the following instead of a single `getline` statement:

```
string input;
while (getline(cin, input))
{
    name += input;
}
```

This reads through every single line in the file, and adds it to the name, while ignoring whitespace (There is none anyway) and line breaks (Which signify the end of a line).

Output:

```
$./hello < test.txt
What is your name?
Hello JohnDoe!
```

Adding a space between the first and last name should be trivial, but I am going off the fact that you said whitespace should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! - The approach was a bit annoying and I wouldn't do it this way in the future but it's for a homework assignment where I had to do it this way